# Count and label each time a word is used

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to find and count the word "Dog" in the text of a HTML page then update the word with the # in front:

Original:
 `The dog chased the cat. The cat killed the dog.`

Modified: 
`The 1dog chased the cat. The cat killed the 2dog.`

This is what I have so far that isn't working:

```
var str = 'Dog';  
int count = 0;
var regex;
var regex = new RegExp(str, "g");
for (var i = 0, i < str.length; i++) {
  counter = count++;
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(regex, counter + "Dog");
}
```

Comment: what is `int count`?

Comment: Also , a typo : `for (var i = 0, ` . what is `,` ?

Comment: yeah i realize i have no idea of whats going on - need someone to help point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the Replace function :

```
var t="The dog chased the cat. The cat killed the dog. so why the dog is eating a dog ?"

i=1;
t=t.replace(/(dog)/ig, function replacer(match, p1) 
  {
   return (i++)+p1;
  });

console.log(t)
```

Result :

> The 1dog chased the cat. The cat killed the 2dog. so why the 3dog is
>   eating a 4dog ?

*(edited to to 1 based counting )*

Comment: Thanks Royi, but how could I turn "var t" to look for specifically "dog" on a webpage (like document.body.innerHTML)?

Answer (score 1):

A trivial change to your code will bring you to a working (I think), but not very good solution:

```
var count = 0;
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(regex,
  function(match) {
    return ++count + match;
  }
);
```

Note that you do not need a loop: `replace` will do the loop for you, as long as you have the `/g` flag.

A problem with this is that you might change things that shouldn't change, such as element names, attribute names and values, javascript code or style rules. A much better (but somewhat involved) solution is to recurse through DOM looking for text nodes, and performing the replacement on their contents.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `replace` function like this:

```
var text = "The dog chased the cat. The cat killed the dog.";
var count = 0;
text.replace(/dog/g,function($0){
    count += 1;
    return count+$0;
})
```